# How to launch standalone browser session?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser, internet-explorer, session

Is it possible to launch new instance of chrome (or any other browser) with standalone session so that it would not log in automatically to applications? What I see now is when I launch new browser instance I log in into web-applications automatically - it has shared session between different instances of one browser. I want browser to allow to test application under several different users without logging in/out all the time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firefox and Chrome both have private browsing modes which don't log you into sites. To access it in Firefox press `Ctrl+Shift+P` and for Chrome press `Ctrl+Shift+N`.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from using private browsing mode - as Adam543i indicated - you can also try the [Multifox](http://br.mozdev.org/multifox/) extension on Firefox. This extension allows Firefox to simultaneously connect to websites using different user names. Seems like overkill but [CookieSwap](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cookieswap/) affects all instances of Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Also, another option is to create [multiple different profiles](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles) for Firefox and then have different shortcuts that link to each different profile. This is what I do - I have one main profile and another clean profile (that I set it to not remember history/cookies/etc.). Also, make sure to set the shortcut to [-no-remote](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Opening_a_new_instance_of_Firefox_with_another_profile) to make it open a new instance.